# Delete Excel worksheets if not in array

Tags: vba, excel

I am having problem to solve the error "time execution error #13: incompatible type". If user creates some worksheet that is not stated in the array, it will be deleted. Can anyone help?

```
sub DeleteNewSheets()

Dim ws, wsP As Worksheet
Dim ArrayOne As Variant

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    ArrayOne = Array("SheetA", "SheetB", "SheetC", "Sheet_n")


    Set wsP = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ArrayOne) ' <--- ERROR #13

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> wsP.Name Then ws.Delete
    Next ws

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

end sub
```

Comment: the index for `worksheets([index])` is an integer (or can be string), but not an array

Comment: u just need to loop through the array to check if a name is matched. If none is matched, then delete the worksheet

Comment: @Rosetta - The index for Worksheets can be an array of strings or integers.  As a test, create a workbook with 3 sheets (Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3), then execute `Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Visible = False`.  Both Sheet1 and Sheet2 will become hidden.

Comment: @Rosetta, thank you for your comments and time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your line of code saying:

```
Set wsP = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ArrayOne)
```

is trying to set a Worksheet object to an array of many Worksheets.  That's like trying to set a single Integer to be an array of Integers.

Try using the following code

```
Sub DeleteNewSheets()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ArrayOne() As Variant
    Dim wsName As Variant
    Dim Matched As Boolean

    ArrayOne = Array("SheetA", "SheetB", "SheetC", "Sheet_n")

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Matched = False
        For Each wsName In ArrayOne
            If wsName = ws.Name Then
                Matched = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If Not Matched Then
            ws.Delete
        End If
    Next ws

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: nice and neat solution. Thank you very much !

Comment: the second `for each` loop could be modified based on "[Using For Each to Loop Through Arrays Is Not Recommended](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/129931)".

Comment: @pcw Thank you too

Answer (score 1):

If you add an extra **For ... Next** or **For Each ... Next** statement to loop through every element in `ArrayOne` and conditional **IF**s statement then it should do the work. So your code should be like this

```
    Sub DeleteNewSheets()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ArrayOne As Variant, iSheet As Integer

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    ArrayOne = Array("SheetA", "SheetB", "SheetC", "Sheet_n")

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For iSheet = LBound(ArrayOne) To UBound(ArrayOne)
            If ws.Name = ArrayOne(iSheet) Then Exit For
            If iSheet = UBound(ArrayOne) Then
                ws.Delete
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

or alternatively

```
Sub DeleteNewSheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ArrayOne As Variant

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    ArrayOne = Array("SheetA", "SheetB", "SheetC", "Sheet_n")

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each Element In ArrayOne
            If ws.Name = Element Then Exit For
            If Element = ArrayOne(UBound(ArrayOne)) Then
                ws.Delete
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: @YowE3K Sorry, I was sloppy. I've fixed it the code so it works properly. Thanks for pointing out my mistake without downvoting my answer. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

you can check sheets in one loop and delete "bad" ones in one shot as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteNewSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sheetsToDelete As String
    Const GOODSHEETS As String = "\SheetA\SheetB\SheetC\Sheet_n\" '<--| list of good sheets names, separated by an invalid character for sheet names 

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If InStr(GOODSHEETS, "\" & ws.Name & "\") = 0 Then sheetsToDelete = sheetsToDelete & ws.Name & "\" '<--| update sheets to be deleted list
    Next ws

    If sheetsToDelete <> "" Then '<--| if the list is not empty
        sheetsToDelete = Left(sheetsToDelete, Len(sheetsToDelete) - 1) '<--| remove last delimiter ("\") from it
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Split(sheetsToDelete, "\")).Delete '<-- delete sheets
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
End Sub
```