# I don't understand how the code read (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

[Delete Excel worksheets if not in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39184341/delete-excel-worksheets-if-not-in-array)

The code below is used to delete worksheets that are not in the array. While the below code can run successfully, there is a problem from my understanding.

As there is a boolean "Matched" declared as False as default (root level), so if wsName = ws.Name, then it will be assigned Matched = True (parent level). So, for those that not wsName = ws.Name, they should be False right?

When those that are not matched and exit for the loop, and run the next line, they are supposed to be False and matched the parent False, but I don't understand why the next line said "If not Matched.." Quite contradict my logical thinking.

I am new to VBA so hope anyone can help me.

Sub DeleteNewSheets()

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ArrayOne() As Variant
Dim wsName As Variant
Dim Matched As Boolean

ArrayOne = Array("SheetA", "SheetB", "SheetC", "Sheet_n")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Matched = False
    For Each wsName In ArrayOne
        If wsName = ws.Name Then
            Matched = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If Not Matched Then
        ws.Delete
    End If
Next ws

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

End Sub

Comment: So for each sheet in the workbook, we do the following: Matched is set to False and then the whole array is checked to see if the workbook name is in the array.  If it is in the array Matched is set to True and we stop checking the array.  When the loop is finished, if Matched is True then we know it was in the array and if Matched is False then it wasn't in the array.  If Matched is False we delete the sheet and then we move on the the next sheet: setting Matched to False and checking the whole array, etc.

Comment: The part I think you need to focus on is that, for each sheet, Matched is set to False and we check the array.  We set Matched to True if we found it but we do NOTHING if we don't find it.  So after the check either Matched is True or it isn't but we need to check the value of Matched to determine if we delete the sheet or not - that's what the `If Not Matched Then` is doing: `If Not Matched Then` is the same as `If Matched <> True Then` - it's checking the value of Matched to see if it is False or True.

Comment: Hi Jerry, first I have to thank your explanation. So, do you mean that for those names that are not in the array, they will be exited for the loop and not be any value related to True / False>

Comment: So, that's why for those that not matched is qualified for "If Matched <> True then"?

Comment: Can those that names that are not in the array can be a False value? Or simply say, they are not a True / False value at all.

Comment: the Matched variable is set to false and it stays false unless the name if found in the array.  Names that are not in the array do not set the value to False - it was already false.  So maybe to make it more understandable change the name of the Matched variable to FoundInArray.  FoundInArray is False unless unless the name was found and in that case it will be set to True.  So then the line after the loop is `If Not FoundInArray Then`

Comment: Maybe it is easier to understand if you replace the line `If Not Matched Then` with `If Matched = False Then` which is the same. Now imagine that the first worksheet is `SheetA` and follow the inner loop in your head.  Then do the same with a worksheet not found in the array. Have a think about this: `(Matched = False) = Not Matched` and `(Matched = True) = Matched = Not Not Matched`.

Comment: Thank you jerry and VBasic2008, Now I have a more clear understanding of this. the most critical part that makes me chaos is "Matched" words and the (Matched = False) = Not Matched and (Matched = True) = Matched = Not Not Matched. I have to adapt the rules and thinking from VBA language. Thank you so  much for help.

Answer (score 0):

### Delete Sheets with Exceptions

- The following (different) approach illustrates how one could deal with some of the issues in the suggested code:

  - Case Sensitivity i.e. `"SheetA" <> "sheetA"`

    - Effectively handled with `StrComp` e.g.
      `If StrComp("SheetA", "sheetA". vbTextCompare) = 0 Then`
    - In this code, it is handled with `Application.Match`.
  - Visibility of the Sheets

    - There has to be at least one visible sheet left (`xlSheetVisible`).
    - You cannot delete a very hidden sheet (`xlSheetVeryHidden`), while you can delete a hidden sheet (`xlSheetHidden`).
  - Workbook Protection (main error handler)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteSheetsTEST()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim Exceptions As Variant
    Exceptions = Array("SheetA", "SheetB", "SheetC", "Sheet_n")
    DeleteSheets wb, Exceptions
End Sub

Sub DeleteSheets( _
        ByVal wb As Workbook, _
        ByVal Exceptions As Variant)
    Const ProcName As String = "DeleteSheets"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Const Title As String = "Delete Sheets"
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim sh As Object
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        dict(sh.Name) = Empty
    Next sh
    
    Dim dictDel As Object: Set dictDel = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim dictKeep As Object: Set dictKeep = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        If IsNumeric(Application.Match(Key, Exceptions, 0)) Then
            dictKeep(Key) = Empty
        Else
            dictDel(Key) = Empty
        End If
    Next Key
    
    If dictDel.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Nothing to delete. No action taken.", vbExclamation, Title
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If dictKeep.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No sheets to keep. No action taken.", vbCritical, Title
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim FoundKeeper As Boolean
    For Each Key In dictKeep.Keys
        If wb.Sheets(Key).Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
            FoundKeeper = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Key
    
    If Not FoundKeeper Then
        MsgBox "No visible sheets to keep. No action taken.", vbCritical, Title
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    For Each Key In dictDel.Keys
        If wb.Sheets(Key).Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden Then
            wb.Sheets(Key).Visible = xlSheetVisible
        End If
    Next Key
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.Sheets(dictDel.Keys).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    MsgBox "Successfully deleted the following sheets:" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Join(dictDel.Keys, vbLf), vbInformation, Title
    
ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you VBasic2008, the approach is very advanced to me, but I will try to read the code from you wrote.

Comment: You are a VBA Master!